# Change div class name with onlick for 3 divs depending on which link div's link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have three divs each with a link inside, when a link is clicked I want the class name of all three divs to change, depending on which link is clicked.

Each div has the class name of w-33 (which makes the div 33% wide), I need the div classes to change to w-60 and w-20.

I have it so the class name changes when the link is clicked but it's only to make the first div w-60 and the other two w-20 regardless of which div link is clicked, I don't know if there's a more efficient way to make it so the div which contains the link that is clicked is the one that gets the w-60 class name other than making three separate functions for each link, so any help is appreciated.

Here are the three divs before the onclick

```
<div class="w-33" id="first-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass()">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="w-33" id="second-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass()">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="w-33" id="third-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass()">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript

```
function changeclass() {
var NAME = document.getElementById("first-project")
NAME.className="w-60 ml-100 mp-100 project"

var NAME = document.getElementById("second-project")
NAME.className="w-20 ml-100 mp-100 project"

var NAME = document.getElementById("third-project")
NAME.className="w-20 ml-100 mp-100 project"
}
```

Here are the three divs after the onclick

```
<div class="w-60" id="first-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass()">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="w-20" id="second-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass()">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="w-20" id="third-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass()">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

So I need it to be if the link in the first div is clicked, its class name will change to w-60 and the other two classes will change to w-20. if the link in the second div is clicked, the first and last class will change to w-20, and the second to w-60, if the third div's link is clicked that will be the div to get the w-60 class name.

Comment: Pass index in function `changeclass(1), changeclass(2), changeclass(3)` and check them inside funciton

Comment: is it ok to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can do that with the help of parameters like this

```
<div class="w-33" id="first-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass(1)">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="w-33" id="second-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass(2)">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="w-33" id="third-project">
<a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass(3)">Learn More</a>
</div>

function changeclass(div_number) {
if(div_number==1)
{
document.getElementById("first-project").className="w-60 ml-100 mp-100 project";
document.getElementById("second-project").className="w-20 ml-100 mp-100 project";
document.getElementById("third-project").className="w-20 ml-100 mp-100 project";
}
if(div_number==2)
{
document.getElementById("second-project").className="w-60 ml-100 mp-100 project";
document.getElementById("first-project").className="w-20 ml-100 mp-100 project";
document.getElementById("third-project").className="w-20 ml-100 mp-100 project";
}

}
```

Comment: That works perfect thank you! Any chance you know how to change the class names back when the link is clicked again?

Comment: Imagine situation when he has 20 such links :-)

Comment: you mean on alternate clicks?

Comment: Alternate clicks and when the link is clicked again to reverse it

Comment: yes ,there are multiple ways to do it  one method is to check the number of clicks , if the count is idd write a set of function if it is even write another

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the event to the function, which will allow you to target the clicked element. So in your inline js it would be `onclick="changeClass(event)`. Then the function would be something like this:

```
    function changeClass(event) {
      // Set all elements classes to their defaults.
      document.getElementById("first-project").classList = ['w-20', 'project'];
      document.getElementById("second-project").classList = ['w-20', 'project'];
      document.getElementById("third-project").classList = ['w-20', 'project'];

      // Set new classes to the clicked element only
      event.target.classList = ['w-60', 'project'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```html
<div class="projects">
    <div class="w-33" id="first-project">
        <a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass(this)">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-33" id="second-project">
        <a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass(this)">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-33" id="third-project">
        <a class="learn-more" onclick="changeclass(this)">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function changeclass(elem) {
        let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.projects > div');
        for(let oneDiv of allDivs) {
            oneDiv.className = "w-20";
        }
        elem.parentNode.className = "w-60";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. I would define css styles in classes in my css file-

for example

```
.selected{
    color: white;
    background: steelblue;
}
```

and i my JS-

```
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
```

now in order to apply css class to an element I would do-

```
resetButton.classList.add("selected");
```

or 
now in order to remove css class to an element I would do-

```
resetButton.classList.remove("selected");
```

or simply toggle

```
resetButton.toggleClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize css selector "adjacent" (".hilight + div" = select all neighbours div of '.hilight')

```js
function hilight (hilightID) {
   var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('w-33');
   for (i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
     const theDiv = allDivs[i];
     const isHilight = theDiv.id === hilightID;
     
     if (isHilight) {
       theDiv.classList.add("hilight");
     } else {
       theDiv.classList.remove("hilight");
     }
   }
 }
```

```css
.container { display: flex; }
.container > div { background: salmon; }

.w-33 { width: 33%; }
.hilight { width: 60%; }
.hilight + div { width: 20%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="w-33" id="first-project">
      <a class="learn-more" onclick="hilight('first-project')">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-33" id="second-project">
      <a class="learn-more" onclick="hilight('second-project')">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-33" id="third-project">
      <a class="learn-more" onclick="hilight('third-project')">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution. pass event to function and add class w-60 to current element.

```js
function changeClass(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.project').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove('w-60');
    el.classList.add('w-20')
  })
  let cls = event.target.parentNode.classList
  cls.remove('w-20');
  cls.add('w-60');
}
```

```css
#group {
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.w-60,
.w-20,
.w-33 {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
   border: 4px solid red;
  transition:all .5s;
}

.w-33 {
  width: 33%;
}

.w-60 {
  width: 60%;
  background: beige;
}

.w-20 {
  width: 19.4%;
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
  <div class="w-33 project" id="first-project">
    <a class="learn-more" onclick="changeClass(event)">Learn More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="w-33 project" id="second-project">
    <a class="learn-more" onclick="changeClass(event)">Learn More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="w-33 project" id="third-project">
    <a class="learn-more" onclick="changeClass(event)">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```